# Converting cartesian coordinates into latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I'm trying to convert a position vector on a unit sphere into the latitude and longitude coordinates but I'm not sure how to do it. I know that the formula for converting the latitude and longitude coordinates into cartesian coordinate is: $$V_n=\begin{pmatrix} R\cos(\lambda_n) \cos(\phi_n) \\ R\sin(\lambda_n) \cos(\phi_n) \\ R\sin(\phi_n) \end{pmatrix}$$ where $\lambda$ represents the longitude and $\phi$ represents the latitude.

Could I get some advice on how to convert cartesian coordinates into latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $V_n/R$. The last element, $z/R=\sin\phi_n$, can be used to get $\phi_n$. You can use $\arcsin$ function, since $\phi_n$ is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ in radians. You might need to convert to degrees, so the answer will be between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. For $\lambda_n$, take the ratio of $y$ and $z$ components, and you can see that you get $\tan\lambda_n$. To get the answer in a $360^\circ$ range, use the [$\mathrm{arctan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function